# Ansible dynamic inventory: Authentication error retrieving ec2 inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamic, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using Ansible's Dynamic Inventory feature to connect to the ec2 instances in AWS account using below:

```
AWS_PROFILE=personal ansible-playbook cifarm.yml -C
```

I have copied the https://raw.github.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py into and https://raw.github.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini file under inventory directory.

On running `AWS_PROFILE=personal ansible-playbook cifarm.yml -C`, it throws below error:

Output:
ERROR: Inventory script (inventory/ec2.py) had an execution error: ERROR: "Authentication error retrieving ec2 inventory.
 - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment vars found but may not be correct
 - Boto configs found at '~/.boto, ~/.aws/credentials', but the credentials contained may not be correct", while: getting EC2 instances

I am running the playbook from a MAC OS. Please note that I am able to run below successfully:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --page-size 5 --profile personal
```

This prooves that the credentials are correct and also I have exported the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

I tried to execute the inventory/ec2.py file as below:

```
./ec2.py --list
```

And it comes back with the same error. I saw a post where it was suggested to update the time on the machine, I am running the playbook. So I ran ntpdate -u

But the issue still persists. I have no idea what is the reason.
Any help/suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. Explaining it here for others to benefit. When I generated the aws credentials for AWS_PROFILE= personal, I had values for below environment variables in ~/.aws/credentials:

1. aws_access_key_id
2. aws_secret_access_key
3. aws_session_token.

However if you look in the ec2.py, it expects variable value called aws_security_token. So all I did was changed the variable name from aws_session_token to aws_security_token in ~/.aws/credentials.

And voila. Works fine.

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue. Was searching around for a while, and this fixed it for me too.

Comment: Created a PR to fix it here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/36742